# Android: Why do Object Animators retain the start value?

Tags: android, objectanimator

I have a mixture of animations running on various scenarios. 
As an example;

I have a fade-in and fade-out animator on a small circle bitmap. On `ACTION_DOWN` the `fade-in` should start
and on `ACTION_UP`, **when the fade-in ends**, fade-out should run. BUT, if the user picks up the finger before the fade-in ends, it should stop right there (`fadein.cancel()`), fade-out should start from THAT alpha value.
I dont want a new object animator each time, I defined an animator like this in the constructor

```
    fadein = Objectanimator.ofFloat(bitmap, "alpha", 1.0f);
    fadeOut = Objectanimator.ofFloat(bitmap, "alpha", 0.0f);
```

What happens is, if I produce the issue as mentioned (picking up the finger fast), the fadeout animator will pick up the alpha value where fade-in left off and it'll RETAIN that. That is, 2nd time onwards it'll NOT pick up a new alpha! Why is that? Whats the workaround? Create new objects each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObjectAnimator` class modifies the attributes of the view, so it updates the property of the view using the setter method of the Object property (as per [official Android Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator)).

So, when `fadein` animation runs, the alpha value is constantly modified, and when `fadein.cancel()` executes, the alpha value of the View stops updating. Let's say this value is `X`.

So, when you start `fadeOut`, it animates from `X` to `0.0f`.

> Whats the workaround?

For `fadeOut`, use [two values imply a starting and ending values](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html#ofFloat%28T,%20android.util.Property%3CT,%20java.lang.Float%3E,%20float...%29)

```
fadeOut = Objectanimator.ofFloat(bitmap, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: How do you animate bitmap?